# Inequality proof: $|f(x)-L| \leq 1 \implies |f(x)| \leq |L| + 1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality, proof-writing

I have an inequality proof relating to inequalities for limits in my intro to real analysis class: $$|f(x)-L| \leq 1 \implies |f(x)| \leq |L| + 1$$

Forgive me I know this proof is painfully simple.

My approach was to use the reverse triangle inequality like so.

---

Proof:

The reverse triangle inequality gives us
$$ |f(x)| - |L| \leq |f(x) - L| \leq 1  $$

adding $|L|$ to all three equations we get

$$ |f(x)| \leq |f(x) - L| + |L| \leq 1 + |L| $$

Therefore 
$$ |f(x)| \leq |L| + 1  \space \space \space  \blacksquare$$

could it be this simple or am I missing something?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Sorry it was an error, edited.

Comment: Your proof is correct. You can also immediately just use $$|f(x)|=|f(x)-L+L| \leq |f(x) -L| +|L|.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps look good. Alternatively observe that $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert \leq 1$ implies $1-L \leq f(x) \leq 1+L$, and 
$$-\lvert L \rvert - 1 \leq -L-1\leq f(x)\leq 1+L \leq 1+|L|$$
which gives $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq  1+\lvert L\rvert$. I am not using triangle inequalities here.